# Reindexing list c#

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to create a list where I can put things at the last place (Enqueue()) and remove object at the first place (Dequeue()). This is my current code:

```
List<Link> list = new List<Link>();

        public void Enqueue(NAW naw)
        {
            Link newLink = new Link();
            list.Add(newLink);
        }

        public NAW Dequeue()
        {
            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                NAW tempNaw = list.ElementAt(0).Naw;
                list.RemoveAt(0);
                return tempNaw;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return list.Count();
        }
```

I try to add an 2 objects and then remove 2 objects but I am not getting the right result. Does anyone see where I went wrong? Thanks

Comment: Why not just use a generic Queue<Link>?

Comment: What are you getting? Looks right to me. BTW, you do realize that the .NET framework already contains a `Queue<T>` class, right?

Comment: .net does have `Queue` you can already use that instead of list

Comment: Your list if of `Link` but when you `Enqueue` you do not use the `NAW`. So when in `Dequeue` you do `.Naw` you will get (probably) null..

Comment: See @Mike_G comment. Regarding your existing code, you do not seem to do anything with `naw` in your `Enqueue` method.

Comment: Thanks using the Queue class right now. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Queue class:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        // New Queue of integers.
        Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>();
        q.Enqueue(1);   // Add 1 to the end of the Queue.
        q.Enqueue(2);  // Then add 2. 1 is at the start.
        q.Enqueue(3);  // Then add 3.
        q.Enqueue(4);  // Then add 4.

        q.Dequeue(); // The integer is removed from the beginning of the Queue.
        Console.WriteLine(q.Peek()); // to take a look of the 1 integer in queue

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

[Queue Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx)